# Saving multiple file names in a directory(win32 c++)

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I want to save multiple file names in the same directory. However it seems to saving only last file in the array.
here is my code:

```
hFind = FindFirstFile("*.bin", &FindFileData);

if(hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

  printf("Not founded");
}
 else {
  printf("Found: %s", FindFileData.cFileName);
}
 if(hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

do
 {
  if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
  {

    printf("\nFound: %s\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
  }
  else
  {

     filesize.LowPart = FindFileData.nFileSizeLow;
     filesize.HighPart = FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh;
     count++;
     filesize.QuadPart += filesize.QuadPart;
     printf("%s %ld bytes", FindFileData.cFileName, filesize.QuadPart);
     printf("count number:%s\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
     files[count] = FindFileData.cFileName;
     printf("\nfiles array:%s", files[count]);

  }
}
 while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0);
 //when I'm printing the file[3], it is showing the last file
printf("file in 3:%s", files[3]);
```

So the problem is the whole array is getting filled with only the last file. Everytime it goes to next file, the whole array is replaced by the last file. I dont know if it's win32 problem or something else. Need your insights. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

files[count] = FindFileData.cFileName;

It copies the address of the FindFileData.cFileName into files[count]. As the address is always the same, all your array items in the files array will always contain the same value.

You have to copy the whole string not just a pointer. Declare the files variable as:

char files[MAC_FILE_COUNT][MAX_PATH];

then replace the line "files[count] = FindFileData.cFileName" with:

strcpy(files[count], FindFileData.cFileName);

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
files[count] = FindFileData.cFileName;
```

does not copy the string, it merely copies of an address. It's a pointer assignment. So every element in `files[]` points to the same block of memory, the character array `FindFileData.cFileName`. So naturally the last value that was copied into `FindFileData.cFileName` is what you see when you look in `files[]`, for all indices.

If you want to copy the string you'll need to use `strcmp`. And you almost certainly are not allocating any memory for the `char*` pointers in `files[]` so you'd need to do that as well. Use `malloc()` and `strlen()`.

However, since you tagged this as C++, I'd abandon using raw arrays, C strings etc., and switch to C++ standard containers. In this case you seem to want `vector<string>`.

Declare the container like this:

```
vector<string> files;
```

And then add items like this:

```
files.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
```

And iterate over the container like this:

```
for(vector<string>::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); ++it) {
    // do something with *it
}
```